# Operating on numerical values in a list, but getting unsupported operand type error?

Tags: python, list, int

```
final_digits = []
for i in added_lists:
    final_digits.append(i % 26)
print final_digits
```

The error I get here is "unsupported oerand type for %: 'list' and 'int', but I iterated through a list containing integers (added lists is a list of numbers)
so why am I getting the error? Shouldn't the integers within the list operate with 26?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (in Python 3, since that's what I happen to have handy):

```
added_lists = [1, 2, 3]
final_digits = []
for i in added_lists:
    final_digits.append(i % 26)
print(final_digits)
```

So I'd suggest that your `added_lists` is not the type you think it is?

Your error message suggests that `added_lists` is probably a list of lists, so `i` is actually a list.

You could print out the value of `type(i)` if it's not obvious, or `repr(added_lists)`.